# Need to remove certain URL paths from URL htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Ok I'm new to ht access and i have been scouring the web for an answer on this.  I currently am using the Interspire shopping cart and the add certain paths in the urls, for example: categories, products, pages and brands before the real SEO part of the url begins.  It sucks. I'm looking for a way to get rid of this in for of a mod_rewite in htaccess.  Here are some more visual examples:

Current: cases.com/**categories**/Amazon-Kindle-Cases/

Want it to be this: cases.com/Amazon-Kindle-Cases/

Current: cases.com/**products**/Piel-Frama-559-iMagnum-Black-Leather-Case-for-Amazon-Kindle-Fire.html

Want it to be this: cases.com/Piel-Frama-559-iMagnum-Black-Leather-Case-for-Amazon-Kindle-Fire.html

Current: cases.com/**brands**/PDair.html

Want it to be: cases.com/PDair.html

Current: cases.com/**pages**/News.html

Want it to be: cases.com/News.html

Do I need a rewrite for each one or can this be done in one.  **Thanks**

Comment: What's wrong with the way it is now? How do you expect to be able to distinguish between requests for brands and pages for example?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(products|brands|pages|categories)
RewriteRule ^(products|brands|pages)(.*)$ $2 [L]
```

Is that working?

more specifically:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^(products|brands|pages|categories)
RewriteRule ^(products|brands|pages)(.*)$ http://cases.com$2 [L]
```

Comment: I need to at categories to this list as well.

RewriteCond $1 ^(categories|products|brands|pages)

RewriteRule ^(categories|products|brands|pages)(.*)$ $2 [L]

It this right?

Comment: Yeah ,it was a quick fix. I'm not thorough with it.
And yes, It will work with category.

Comment: @GuyPierce    Add  `RewriteEngine on`  on the line before those two lines.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^(products|brands|pages)
RewriteRule ^(products|brands|pages)(.*)$ http://cases.com/$2 [L]`

Comment: @GuyPierce  consider accepting this as a solution if it's working out. :-) .

Comment: Yes I will as soon as I have it tested. Just doing a couple other thing real fast.

Comment: @GuyPierce  Have you tested the given solution yet?